# TimeSeries with a groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to look at `TimeSeries` data for every client over various time periods in `Pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
clients = np.random.randint(1, 11, size=100)
dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=365)
OrderDates = random.sample(list(dates),100)
Values = np.random.randint(10, 250, size=100)


df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Client' : clients,'OrderDate' : OrderDates, 'Value' : Values})

df = df.sort_values(['OrderDate', 'Client'], ascending=['True', 'True'])

df.head()
#     Client  OrderDate  Value
# 36       3 2013-01-11     40
# 55       4 2013-01-12    192
# 54       8 2013-01-15    130
# 48      10 2013-01-17    153
# 78       9 2013-01-22    171
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the count and the sum of the 'Value' column, grouped by 'Client' for various time periods (Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly - I will likely build 3 different dataframes for this data, then make the dataframes 'wide').

For Quarterly, I would expect something like this:

```
Client      OrderDate       NumberofEntries SumofValues
1           2013-03-31      7               28
1           2013-06-30      2               7
1           2013-09-30      6               20
1           2013-12-31      1               3
2           2013-03-31      1               4
2           2013-06-30      2               8
2           2013-09-30      3               17
2           2013-12-31      4               24
```

I could append that data frame by getting the quarter for each entry (or Month, or Year), then use `Pandas` `groupby` function, but that seems like it's extra work when I should be using `TimeSeries`.

I've read the documentation and reviewed a `TimeSeries` demonstration by Wes, but I don't see a way to do a `groupby` for the Client, then perform the `TimeSeries` over the time periods I am trying to build (Alternatively - I could run a `for loop` and build the dataframe that way, but again - seems like that's more work than there should be.)

Is there a way to combine a `groupby` process with `TimeSeries`?

Answer (score 13):

A slight alternative is to `set_index` before doing the groupby:

```
In [11]: df.set_index('OrderDate', inplace=True)

In [12]: g = df.groupby('Client')

In [13]: g['Value'].resample('Q', how=[np.sum, len])
Out[13]: 
                   sum  len
Client OrderDate           
1      2013-03-31  239    1
       2013-06-30   83    1
       2013-09-30  249    2
       2013-12-31  506    3
2      2013-03-31  581    4
       2013-06-30  569    4
       2013-09-30  316    4
       2013-12-31  465    5
...
```

Note: you don't need to do the sort before doing this.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you could use `resample` directly on the groupby! Still so much features hidden and undocumented .. (OK, I know you can see it in tab completion, but that's not so visible).

Comment: And indeed, much cleaner to do the `set_index` before! (I was thinking this would give problems for the resample with it then being a multi-index,  but of course, the groups itself don't have the grouping value as an index yet)

Comment: @joris atm resample just passes to g.apply(pd.DataFrame.resample), but perhaps in the future the groupby method could be written specifically and be more efficient... :)

Comment: @AndyHayden While trying to run this, line 11 in your code above (df = df.set_index('OrderDate', inplace=True)) blanks out my DF.  Prior to line 11, I run `type(df)` and get: `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.  After I run `df = df.set_index('OrderDate', inplace=True)`, then `type(df)`, I get: `NoneType`.  `pd.__version__` = `0.12.0`.  Will this only work on 0.13?  Thanks

Comment: @mikebmassey Sorry, I had a typo, if this is inplace you don't need to `df = `.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this? I'm first doing a groupby, and then applying a resample on each group.

```
In [11]: grouped = df.groupby('Client')

In [12]: result = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.set_index('OrderDate').resample('Q', how=[np.sum, len]))

In [13]: result['Value']
Out[13]: 
                    sum  len
Client OrderDate            
1      2013-03-31   227    4
       2013-06-30   344    2
       2013-09-30   234    1
2      2013-03-31   299    2
       2013-06-30   538    4
       2013-09-30   236    2
       2013-12-31  1124    7
3      2013-03-31   496    4
       2013-06-30   NaN    0
       2013-09-30   167    2
       2013-12-31   218    1
```

---

Update: with the suggestion of @AndyHayden in his answer, this becomes much cleaner code:

```
df = df.set_index('OrderDate')
grouped = df.groupby('Client')
grouped['Value'].resample('Q', how=[np.sum, len])
```